# Extract time/datetimes with time zone info intact into Java8 OffsetTime / OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, jdbc, java-8

How do I extract, with time zone info kept intact, into Java8 `java.time.OffsetTime` and `java.time.OffsetDateTime` objects, database values that have SQL Types `TIME_WITH_TIME_ZONE` / `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE`?  *I.e.*, if the database has a time with a zone that is `+03:00` or `-05:00`, I would like that time zone specificity preserved in the `OffsetTime` and `OffsetDataTime` objects I create from the database values.

In my specific case the times and timestamp values are coming from MS SQLServer, but I don't *think* that should matter...  [Edit: Looks like MS SQLServer only has `datetimeoffset` that is timezone-aware, nothing to support `TIME_WITH_TIME_ZONE`.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible using 2nd argument to getObject(), I haven't got a MS SQLServer instance to test this with though...

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnfoo = 500");
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.print("Column 1 returned ");
    OffsetDateTime localDate = rs.getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class);
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Note this only appears be available in 4.2 and later versions of the JDBC driver for your database that are Java 8 aware... See [release note for 4.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/jdbc-4-2-compliance-for-the-jdbc-driver)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.